# How to determine which user is currently logged in?

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, active-directory

I have a piece of software that can be run my multiple users on the same machine.  For some reason, when one user is logged in, and another user is logged in but in the background (processes remain running, but user is not actively logged in), any of the processes that run on a timer that require network access throw an error.

I am wondering if there is a way to determine on a Windows machine with multiple users logged in, which user is the currently logged in user.  For example, `User A` is logged in, starts the program, then goes on break.  `User B` logs in using "switch user" in Windows 7.  `User B` then starts the program as well.  The program is still running for `User A`, but `User A` no longer has access to the network.  Is there a way to determine that `User B` is the active user, so I can add the error handling into my program, and stop filling my error logs with messages from User A that the specified network name is no longer available?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I have something that handles this for other situations, so I will just add the same functionality where I need it.  For anyone who comes across this with a similar need, I added the following in main `Form_Load`:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler SystemEvents.SessionSwitch, AddressOf AccountSwitch
    ......
End Sub
```

and the `AccountSwitch` subroutine:

```
Private Sub AccountSwitch(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SessionSwitchEventArgs)
    If e.Reason = SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock Then
        _flgLocked = True
    Else
        _flgLocked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, simply check for `_flgLocked` anywhere that you need to ensure that the user is the currently logged in account.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this will only work if the user is not active due to the computer going to sleep.  Does anyone know of a way to also handle if a different user logs in?

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking needs some clarification.

(Q) Is the process being started by UserA supposed to be used by ANY user?

(Q) Why don't you just start up multiple processes one for each user?  So UserA gets one instance of the process, then UserB gets it's own instance.

The concept of a current user is really only valid for userland processes any daemon process (like a shared services) should not be interacting with *the current user* because the process is running on behalf of multiple users.

If the process is trying to access user shares (E:, F: etc), then the process **is, or should be** a userland process.

On a terminal server, multiple users can be simultaneously active so if your process were running on a server then **multiple current users exist**.

If you want to handle the current user consider looking up information about Window Stations (every user that logs in gets a User Station), see process explorer and for me the windows station handle is named `\Sessions\1\Windows\WindowStations\WinSta0`
On a terminal server multiple Windows Stations will exist, one for each user that is logged on and has a GUI (aka Windows Desktop) running.

Process Explorer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Windows Stations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winstation/window-stations

I know this isn't what you were looking for but hopefully it helps you approach the problem differently (start separate app per user and go to sleep when user is not active).

- [How to handle switch user in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293922/how-to-handle-switch-user-in-c)