# How to handle switch user in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to do a set of task in my windows forms application when user switches from one account to other using the Switch user option provided by windows 7.So do we have some system event to handle this switch user case?

Answer (score 4):

I think [`SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you need. You can listen to a new user logging in and count that as a user switch, since your app is still active (else you would have a logoff first).

> Occurs when the currently logged-in user has changed.

I guess the logic for a user switch is:

- The current session is still alive (didn't logoff);
- Another session logs in or unlocks.

Both events can be handled by this event.

Comment: it is a win forms application and whenever user switches the account a new instance will get created and I guess we donot session kind of thing in win forms.

Comment: But applications run per user. That's just the way it works. Maybe you need a service instead.

Comment: Thanks, but my current constraints does not support the service.

Comment: Then use the existing methods as described in the answer. There is no way to have a single app travel across user sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I didn't see a helpful answer. You do need to handle the [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch(VS.85).aspx) event. When a Windows user switches to another user, the SessionSwitchEventArgs from the event will have a Reason property that is a [SessionSwitchReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason(v=vs.110).aspx) enum with the value of "ConsoleDisconnect". When the user switches back, it should have a value of "ConsoleConnect".